# error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date, How to properly format a date?

Tags: java, android, date

I'm trying to format this way any input String or Date to "MMM dd, yyyy" :

```
public Date format(Object date) {
    if (date instanceof String) {
        date = stringToDate(date + "");
    }
    return stringToDate(dateToString((Date) date));
}

public String dateToString(Date date) {
    return (new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy")).format(date);
}

public Date stringToDate(String dateStr) {
    try {
        return (new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy")).parse(dateStr); // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR MESSAGE TRIGGERS
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

But, proceeding this way I get an error message saying:

> ```
> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Sep 11 00:00:00 UTC+01:00 2014" (at offset 0)
> 09-11 22:44:30.590  29020-29020/com.mypharmacy.app W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
> 09-11 22:44:30.590  29020-29020/com.mypharmacy.app W/System.err﹕ at com.mypharmacy.helpers.DateHelper.stringToDate(DateHelper.java:26)
> 09-11 22:44:30.590  29020-29020/com.mypharmacy.app W/System.err﹕ at com.mypharmacy.helpers.DateHelper.format(DateHelper.java:15)
> 09-11 22:44:30.590  29020-29020/com.mypharmacy.app W/System.err﹕ at com.mypharmacy.dao.DrugDAOImpl.getAll(DrugDAOImpl.java:55)
> ```

How to fix this, please ?

Comment: do you think you are parsing with right format ?

Comment: Well what are you passing in? It's unless why you'd cast to a `Date` and then format and parse... what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: The input Object can be String or Date, if it's String it will be casted into Date. @JonSkeet, I'm casting (Date), because the input is instance of `Object`.

Comment: @user3797031: But my point is that if it's already a `Date`, why not just return it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'm trying to format the default Date format to that specified one.

Comment: Your problem is the string is not in the same format as your `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @user3797031: You're returning a `Date` value. Do you understand that a `Date` doesn't *have* a format?

Comment: @JonSkeet, how to get the current date and parse it to "MMM dd, yyyy", please ?

Comment: You don't *parse* to a string - you *format* to a string. It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve, or even why. To get a string representation of the current date and time, you can create a new `SimpleDateFormat`, then use `sdf.format(new Date())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format seems to be incorrect for  "Thu Sep 11 00:00:00 UTC+01:00 2014"

It looks more like

ddd MMM M HH:mm:ss K YYYY

???

Comment: how to get the current date and parse it to "MMM dd, yyyy", please ?